# Package running in SSDT but not through the Execute Package Utility

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I created a package that will run in SSDT, but it will not run through the execute package utility when saved to the filesystem.  Perhaps there is an easy fix, but I am unaware of one, and googling didn't seem to yield anything useful.

I am running SQL Server Enterprise 2017, as well as Visual Studio 2017 with the most recent version of SSDT.  I have tried installing SQL Server 2018 to no avail.

The point is scheduling the package, one solution would be for package to run through DTExec.exe, alternatively if there is a way to automate running the package through SSDT that would also work.

The error:

> To run a SSIS Package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.

The catch:

afaik I have SQL server enterprise installed as I can save SSIS packages to the file system through the SQL Server Import Export Wizard (before I received enterprise edition it said originally it required SQL server standard edition or higher to save the packages)

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have only installed SSMS. Can you connect to a SQL Server through SSMS and run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: I can; looks like the server I am working from is SQL Server 2012, but I doubt the server is the issue as this will run fine through SSDT.  I definitely have more than SSMS installed, though, as I can use the import export wizard and create packages and all.

Comment: Installing SSMS allows you to use the import/export wizard. Installing SSDT allows you to create packages. You don't need SQL Server installed to do either of these things. When you connect to SQL Server to check the version, is this SQL Server on your computer or a different one? What does `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` return?

Comment: it returns the servername, and @@version returns the version of the server...in this case SQL Server 2012.

Comment: _is this SQL Server on your computer or a different one?_

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have selected the Integration Services check box while installing SQL Server features. It looks like you have installed SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio which allows you to create SSIS packages but you didn't install SSIS feature which is required to execute packages.

You can refer to the following official documentation for additional information:

- [Install Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Well the weird thing is I can run packages.  Just not this one.  I can create packages through the import/export wizard and run them just fine, and I can create packages through SSDT and run them just fine.  The only issue is when I am merging two sources when creating the package in SSDT.  At that point it will run in visual studio, but I can't run the package with the execute utility.  I'll try reinstalling; who knows maybe that'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have select the relevant `TargetServerVersion` property in the project configuration. You can refer to the following link for more information:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)